# Can't connect to remote mysql when I use domain as a host (Linode issue)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, linode

For example, I use Laravel, PDO driver, Nginx, Ubuntu 12.04.

Database settings. `example.com` points to MySQL server. This code works on Google Cloud, AWS, DigitalOcean, but does not work on Linode.

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => 'example.com',
'database' => 'db',
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
```

On Linode I have to set IP of the database server directly

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => '1.2.3.4',
'database' => 'db',
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
```

Or I'll get an error

```
*1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have a firewall installed on the server? Check the netstat to check if it is listening on the wildcard address.

Comment: Yes for firewall installed or for "it is listening on the wildcard address"

Comment: root@localhost:~# `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

in case of your server does not has firewall, it should be work:

Change mysql config

Start with editing mysql config file

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment out following lines.

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

If you do not find skip-networking line, add it and comment out it.

Restart the mysql server.

```
service mysql restart
```